# Dart Getting error: Undefined name 'csvCodec'. (undefined_identifier) when using csv package

Tags: csv, dart

Getting error -
`error: Undefined name 'csvCodec'. (undefined_identifier at [easy_csv] example\exa.dart:10)`

I implemented [decoder example](https://github.com/close2/csv/blob/e786f40d19e19ee7cebd51dbf182a8b539b86696/README.md#L53) [from dart csv package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/csv) like -

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

main() async {
  final input = new File('foo.csv').openRead();
  final fields =
      await input.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(csvCodec.decoder).toList();
}
```

Comment: [Issue is now solved.](https://github.com/close2/csv/issues/28#issuecomment-480211916) As with Dart 2, csv was no longer able to be a codec & corresponding documentation was not removed, which is [now updated](https://github.com/close2/csv/commit/6f592adcfdbcebfb7546587e96f3917ee2782221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Issue is now solved.](https://github.com/close2/csv/issues/28#issuecomment-480211916)

> As with Dart 2, csv was no longer able to be a codec & corresponding
>   documentation was not removed.
>   This change is [now reflected](https://github.com/close2/csv/commit/6f592adcfdbcebfb7546587e96f3917ee2782221)  in [documentation](https://github.com/close2/csv/blob/6f592adcfdbcebfb7546587e96f3917ee2782221/README.md#53)

---

Example code for reading csv file & printing them on according latest version 4.0.3

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

main() async { 
  //TODO Change file_name
  String file_name = 'foo.csv';
  final input = File(file_name).openRead();
  //Every csv row is converted to a list of values. 
  //Unquoted strings looking like numbers (integers and doubles) are by default converted to ints or doubles.
  final fields = await input.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(new CsvToListConverter()).toList();
  print(fields);
}
```